# PHP Autolinking Usernames

Tags: php, detection

I want to create a Autolinking solution for my Site. It's just about the Usernames, if a username is found in the string, it should create a link to the profile. Well, I had now just two possible solutions in mind:

1. While extracting the usernames to give them an invisble special char as a kind of identifier and regex trough it. But this is just kind of a "luck" based solution and it won't go right in user-written texts.
2. Getting a whole frking username array and pulling trough it everytime... I could reduce the serverload by reducing the detection to a limited factor as... let's say just the friends of the autor. But somehow this would be unstatisfying as well.

I would be glad for any kind of hint you may have. Usable are PHP, JS (JQuery FW).

Comment: What about false positives? e.g. user Fred talking about Fettucine Alfredo?

Comment: In fact you are right, I also thought about that in fact. But on the other hand it's hopefully not that big of a deal, as it's for an anime and gaming page -> and they usually tend to get quite "unique" Usernames and one or 2 "misslinks" per post should be OK, as users tend to get used to the behavior of a system. But I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mimick Twitter and StackOverflow (using `@`), you could use something like this ([demo](http://ideone.com/Whf7C)):

```
preg_replace('~(^|\s)@([[:alnum:]_]+)~', '$1<a href="/profile/$2/">@$2</a>', $string);
```

Comment: In fact... I didn't think about twitter :D, you are right the @ will be the easy solution! I guess I'll go with that. Thanks for the hint :).

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to make hash tags links. You could you use a similar method with @ symbols and a quick query.

```
function addhashtags($text) {
$text = preg_replace('/#([\\d\\w]+)/', '<a href="/?h=$1">$0</a>', $text);
return $text;
}
```